# BIND DNS Zone Fowarders vs. NS Type Records

Tags: dns, bind

Is there a big difference between setting a DNS Zone to have `type foward;`, and setting an NS record for another name server in the zone file? Does one have better performance/speed? Or am I completely missing the point, and they are completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there is a difference between the two scenarios... adding NS records is creating a delegation (and you can only do so for subzones when you are authoritative for the parent zone, adding forwarders are simply that. Performance/speed don't really come into it as they are used for different purposes.

Delegation is used when you want delegate the management of a subzone to another server. E.g. you own corp.com, you could delegate the subzone of engineering.corp.com to the engineering team's name server. This is how the whole Internet DNS hierarchy works, zones are delegated down from the root.

Conditional forwarding is used when you want to directly bounce queries sideways to a specific name server which is responsible for a specific domain. If the owner of corp.com bought company.com then during the merging phase when you want internal DNS access available to both companies, you may want to add forwarders for each company in the other's name server, the servers then know where to forward queries to directly instead of traversing the Internet hierarchy and getting the external name servers for either company.

Steve